# Saxon: Is there a way to set variables in an xpath query?

Tags: saxon

Does Saxon have an equivilent to ADO.NET/JDBC setParameter() where I can do something like the following:
var query = XPath.createQuery("/root/name/[@first = @param1]");
query.setParam("@param1", "dave");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath allows variables in XPath expressions, a variable reference is used with `$varName`. So in Saxon .NET with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XPathCompiler.html you can use

```
var processor = new Processor();
var xpathCompiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();
xpathCompiler.DeclareVariable(new QName("param1"));
var xpathSelector = xpathCompiler.Compile("/root/name/[@first = $param1]").Load();
xpathSelector.SetVariable(new QName("param1"), new XdmAtomicValue("dave"));
```

Comment: This is for Saxon on .NET, the equivalent for Saxon on Java is very similar.